# ajax on empty result, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

what should I use if i have an empty result coming from C# method.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Me.aspx/Load",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

            success: function (msg) {

                    alert(msg.d);
                }

});
```

is not alerting when is empty.

I have tried:

```
msg.length===0
```

and

```
error:
```

but couldn't make it work.

thank you.

Comment: try (if msg.length) { console.log="we have it"} else { console.log('we dont have it')}

Comment: The `success` method may receive two parameters, the second one describes the status of the request. Try to `alert` the second parameter and see what you get.

Comment: @rbyte How do I get second parameter, thanks

Comment: Try something like this: `success: function( msg, status ) { alert(status); }` and let us know what you got.

Comment: no sor on either way it alerts success

Comment: Ok, then there may be occurring and error with you request. Replace the property `success` by `complete` and let us know what happened.

Comment: Use a javascript debugger, firebug or chrome dev tools or another tool of your choice, to view the server response, then add it to your question so we can tell what you're dealing with.

Comment: when I use `complete` it also acts the same way, and also never gives me the result message as it used to on `success`

Comment: The best way to check if an error has occurred with your request is through the `error` method. Add this to your ajax object, after the `success` function: `error: function( msg, status ) { alert(status); }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the result is an empty string, then you should check for an empty string:

```
msg === ''
```

Sorry, even better:

```
if (msg) {...}
```

If msg is anything that is **not** :

- false
- 0
- null
- '' (empty string)
- NaN
- undefined

it evaluates to `true`.

What are you expecting from the server?

**EDIT**: return an object with a success property, something like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    ...
}
```

and then check for

```
if (msg.success) { ... do stuff ...}
```

**REEDIT**

I don't know how it works in C#, but you have to serialize the object you are working with in the server. Let's say this is your (failure) object:

```
response // and response.success = false
```

So, you should do something like:

```
print json_encode(response);
```

So that it is returned to your JS programme.

Comment: it did not work. it seems like success: is not even firing when result is empty

Comment: do i get it on some other properties??

Comment: Maybe you should send from the server an json object with a property .success = boolean value, to check if there should be an action. Then you just check `if (msg.success) {...}`

Comment: no unfortunately, none of those conditions worked on empty,maybe I am doing something wrong

Comment: are you sending response back from server properly. Remember you will have to print/echo the response back to client

Comment: @ikaros45 I use JavaScriptSerializer on my C# side.

Comment: ok, I used `if (msg.d.length) {
                    console.log('not empty');
                }
                else {
                    console.log('empty');
                }` and it worked. Thank you all for your contributions

Comment: I think it's a cleaner solution to include a boolean success property in the object you are serializing and just check in a clear way in the server `if (msg.success) {...}`. Anyway, happy to help!

Comment: @ikaros45 when i check firebug on my response I see `{"d":"[[\"5329\",\"kol\"]]"}`, that way I get `msg.d`, but how can I add another element, so that i can get msg.success. some tutorial s might help I am in confusion. thanks

Comment: You have to add the success property in the server. If `output` is your object/dictionary in the server, add another property (or element if you work with a dict) so that `output.success = true` (or false). In the client you should get `{"d": "blablabla", "success": true}`